# Multiple Choice Quiz using Python loops

Tags: python, loops, data-analysis

I am having issues understanding loops in python. Also I am having problems understanding how to add loops to my Python Quiz assignment. Can someone please give me guidance on this issue of mine. Below is my current code on my python multiple choice quiz.

```
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()

# showing the current date you're taking the quiz
print("Today's Date is:") 
print('%s/%s/%s' % (now.month, now.day, now.year))

print("")

#this will print out my welcome statement and ask you for your name
print('Hello welcome to my Quiz, what is your name?')


#definied the variable username so that the user could type in their name
usersname = input()
print ("")
print('It is nice to meet you, ' + usersname)

print("")
level = input ('Please select a difficulty (easy, medium, or hard): ')

print("")#I just used this to add some space between my lines
print("")#I just used this to add some space between my lines

#these are my questions 

easy_questions= ["What is 20 + 2 __1__", "What is the capital of Georgia__2__","If john has $4 and buys a candy bar for $3.50, how much money does he have left over__3__","What is the name of the NBA basketball team in Georgia__4__","What is the name of the NFL team in Georgia__5__","How many toys do I have if I sell 3, but had 8 toys originally__6__","How many Bad Boy movies are there__7__","How many Fast Furious movies are there__8__","What is 10 * 5 __9__","What city does the UGA team play in__10__"]

medium_questions= ["What is 20 + 2 __1__", "What is the capital of Georgia__2__","If john has $4 and buys a candy bar for $3.50, how much money does he have left over__3__","What is the name of the NBA basketball team in Georgia__4__","What is the name of the NFL team in Georgia__5__","How many toys do I have if I sell 3, but had 8 toys originally__6__","How many Bad Boy movies are there__7__","How many Fast Furious movies are there__8__","What is 10 * 5 __9__","What city does the UGA team play in__10__"]

hard_questions= ["What is 20 + 2 __1__", "What is the capital of Georgia__2__","If john has $4 and buys a candy bar for $3.50, how much money does he have left over__3__","What is the name of the NBA basketball team in Georgia__4__","What is the name of the NFL team in Georgia__5__","How many toys do I have if I sell 3, but had 8 toys originally__6__","How many Bad Boy movies are there__7__","How many Fast Furious movies are there__8__","What is 10 * 5 __9__","What city does the UGA team play in__10__"]
```

Comment: you mean like `for(var i=0;i<len(hard_questions);i++) print(hard_questions[i])  //your logic now `

Comment: Yes I want to understand how the for loop works to print my questions. If I could trouble you, can you explain what this means. I would like to understand it fully, so that I can pay forward.

Comment: a for loop is basically a "counter". my for loop counts from 0 --> `var i=0`  to the length of your `hard_questions` array --->`i<len(hard_questions)`.with this you can print out all questions at once. of course you need to add extra logic, so that you only print another question, if the previous one is answered correct.

Comment: I am honestly still lost? these loop functions are not easy for me to understand. :(

Answer (score 1):

Loops are very elementary (in any language), so I would highly recommend you read up on them. Here is a useful link: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/python_loops.htm

You could do something like this:

```
for question in easy_questions:
    answer = input(question)
    check_if_answer_is_correct(answer)
```

Comment: Thank you I know they are elementary, but I've just started learning python and I am having to create a multiple choice quiz as my 1st project and I see using a loop in my code would save me a lot of steps in writing unnecessary code. Thank you again!

Comment: I didn't mean it in a disrespectful way. I meant it in a "it's crucial that you understand them to move forward" way

Comment: Its is ok I understand I had to think about it thank you for the assistance. I will more than likely come to again the future.